# Do something before UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

Now I have a question that if we don't have the access to save photo into album, the app will crash. So I want to ask for the access at the beginning. But if the Users select NO, the app will crash when the app is saving photos. So I want to judge whether we have the access before using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` function. Except adding codes before per `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` function, any else methods can be used?

Comment: It's probably crashing because you don't have the `NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription` key in your Info.plist.

Comment: yes, I know that. But using the function , `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`, will not pop the alert to ask you for access. It will crash. So I want to use `runtime`? or else method to rewrite this function to fix it up.@rmaddy

Comment: Where is your app crashing? What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing because you need to set

> NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription

in **info.plist** file

then after use following code to check access of gallery

```
PHAuthorizationStatus status = [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus];
if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
    // Access has been granted.
    NSLog(@"Access Granted");
   UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Mobile.png"];
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);


}

else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
    // Access has been denied.
     NSLog(@"Access NOT Granted");
    UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Not Granted"
                                                                   message:@"You have not granted permission for a gallery to save photos, Please grant it from setting"
                                                            preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                          handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];

    [alert addAction:defaultAction];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

}

else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {

    // Access has not been determined.
    [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status) {

        if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
            UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Mobile.png"];
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(myImage, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
        }

        else {
            // Access has been denied.
        }
    }];
}

else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusRestricted) {
    // Restricted access - normally won't happen.
}
```

Don't forget to `#import <Photos/Photos.h>`

Don't forget to implement this method

```
- (void) image:(UIImage*)image didFinishSavingWithError:(NSError *)error contextInfo:(NSDictionary*)info{
}
```